# Forward returns measurment?

Tags: returns, forward, performance-evaluation, return, performance

Is there a common approach to measure how a forward contract is performing?

Here's what I'm thinking, each day you would price your forward with the next formula.

$$
F_t = S_0 e^{-r_f T}-Ke^{-r T} = (S_0 e^{(r-r_f) T}-K)e^{-r T}=(FWD_t -K)e^{-r T}
$$

With $K$ being the forward price originally agreed.

Now I'd think a common approach for the daily return would be:

$$
r_t = (\frac{F_{t}}{F_{t-1}}-1) 
$$

However usually $F_0= 0$, which would create a problem for return of the first day.  Is there any other common practice to measure this?

Thanks

Comment: In the first equation what are $r$ and $r_f$?

Comment: risk free domestic rate and risk free foreign rate respectively